# How to populate Core Data / SQLite DB with contents of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an `NSMutableArray` named `usersArray` that I would like to populate a Core Data / SQLite DB / store.  So far I have the following method constructed, but I don't think it will populate correctly, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
- (void)populateCDDB:(NSMutableArray *)usersArray {

    NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:usersArray];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:_context]];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *objectsForImport = [_context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSArray *importKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username", @"pin", @"credit", @"email", @"lastLogin", @"rfid", @"phoneNumber", nil];

    for (NSManagedObject *object in objectsForImport) {
//        NSMutableArray *anObjectArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[importKeys count]];
        for (NSString *key in importKeys) {
            id value = [object valueForKey:key];
            if (!value) {
                value = @"";
            }
            [usersArray addObject:[value description]];
        }
    }
    //save the results to Core Data / SQLite store.
    [_context save:&error];
}
```

And yes `usersArray` is an instance variable for the class.

Comment: It's difficult to tell what you're trying to achieve.  Are you reading from CoreData, or writing to to (or updating)?  What's in the usersArray?  How is your entity Account defined?

Comment: @pbasdf I'm trying to put the objects in the `NSMutableArray` into the entity `Account`

Comment: What class are the objects in the array?

Comment: @pbasdf I believe all the objects in the array are of type `NSString`.

Comment: I can't see how the strings in the array match up with the `importKeys` and/or the attributes of the `Account` entity.  Can you post an NSLog of the `usersArray`?

Comment: @pbasdf yeah I think I understand what your getting at.  I implemented the method from the below answer into the class, and I'm getting the following crash, https://gist.github.com/ipatch/6ff44d2d703f02ad2f74  The `usersArray` isn't key value coding compliant, and that is why the app is crashing when I try to import the `usersArray` into a Core Data context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I understand the comment to mean that you want to use the objects in the array as a source for creating "Account" objects in core data.

From the data gathered from the question, I assume that both your objects in the array and the core data "Account" entity support all of the keys.

Since you didn't specify a type or API for the objects in the array, I assume they are key-value compliant on the names you listed earlier, and the types are compatible.

```
- (BOOL)addUsersFromArray:(NSArray*)usersToAdd
                  intoMOC:(NSManagedObjectContext*)moc
                    error:(NSError**)error {
    NSArray *importKeys = @[@"pin", @"credit", @"email", @"lastLogin", @"rfid", @"phoneNumber"];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Account"];
    for (id user in usersToAdd) {
        id username = [user valueForKey:@"username"];
        // See if we already have an Account for this user - username is unique key
        fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username = %@", username];
        NSArray *fetched = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:error];
        if (fetched == nil) return NO;

        NSManagedObject *account = [fetched firstObject];
        if (account == nil) {
            account = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
            [account setValue:username forKey:@"username"];
        }
        for (NSString *key in importKeys) {
            id value = [user valueForKey:key];
            if (value) {
                [account setValue:value forKey:key];
            }
        }

    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the very thorough answer.  I slightly modified your answer, and I'm getting this crash when trying to run this method, https://gist.github.com/ipatch/6ff44d2d703f02ad2f74

Comment: That's because the data item in the array is a string.  It's your array, so you should know what's in it.  Either make it KVC compliant (note a dictionary can be used here) or change the code to properly interpret each item in the array.  If the array contains "formatted strings" then you may have to parse each string.  NSLog the array, and post the contents if you need help parsing it.